# Android XML pullmarser from URL

Tags: android, xml

I need help on one of my projects. I am a new android developer and i'm looking to create an app that parses some xml. I have gotten it to work when my xml file is in assets, but how can a use an online xml file to parse?

```
package com.adiboy101.nextbusvancouver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.adiboy101.nextbusvancouver.beans.NextBus;
import com.adiboy101.nextbusvancouver.xml.XMLPullParserHandler;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView;
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    List<NextBus> employees = null;
    try {
        XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();
        employees = parser.parse(getAssets().open("example.xml"));
        ArrayAdapter<NextBus> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<NextBus>(this,R.layout.list_item, employees);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the remote xml file from your server with `HTTP` connection into a `String`

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(file_url);
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
try {
String response = client.execute(get, responseHandler); // xml response
    XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();
    /*
        your parsing code here
    */
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "your parsing code here" can I get an example? Thanks!

Comment: that same code you used in your question; in `onCreate` method (in try catch block) !